# I am unable to retrieve the second value in Shared Preference

Tags: android, sms, sharedpreferences

In my example, i am entering mobile no., message content in one activity. Before leaving that activity i am saving that info in **"Shared Preference"**. In other activity i am trying to get those mob no,message,i am able to get no but unable to getting that message(second value).please help me to solve the issue.

**DefaultDetails.java**

```
package com.example.nirbhaya;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DefaultDetails extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button save,reset;
    EditText dMob,dMsg,dEmail;
    String defMobNo,defMsg,defEmail;
    SharedPreferences DefaultData;

    private static final String TAG = "DD-Activity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.defaultdetails);

        initializing();

    }
    private void initializing() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bsave1);
        reset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bReset);

        dMob = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDefMobNo);
        dMsg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDefMsg);
        dEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDefEmail);

        save.setOnClickListener(this);
        reset.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(arg0.getId())
        {
        case R.id.bsave1:
            defMobNo = dMob.getText().toString();
            defMsg = dMsg.getText().toString();
            defEmail = dEmail.getText().toString();
                Log.i(TAG,"DONE");
                DefaultData = getSharedPreferences("defMobileNo",0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor store = DefaultData.edit();
                store.putString("defMobileNo", defMobNo);
                store.putString("defMessgae", defMsg);
                store.putString("defEMail", defEmail);
                store.commit();
                Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), CurrentDetails.class);
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            break;
        case R.id.bReset:
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDefMobNo)).setText("");
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDefEmail)).setText("");
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDefMsg)).setText("");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**DefSMS.java**

```
package com.example.nirbhaya;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DefSms extends Activity{

    Button buttonSend;
    String defNo,defMsg;
    SharedPreferences DefaultData;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.defsms);

        DefaultData = getSharedPreferences("defMobileNo",0);
        final String defNo = DefaultData.getString("defMobileNo","Couldn't load data");

        DefaultData = getSharedPreferences("defMessgae",0);
        final String defMsg = DefaultData.getString("defMessgae","Couldn't load data");

        buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);

        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(defNo, null, defMsg, null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

> Here def no getting message as **Couldn't load data**
>   please help me

Comment: remove this line **DefaultData = getSharedPreferences("defMessgae",0);** in DefSMS.java

Comment: Yes, now it's working but how?

Comment: You were trying to get shared preference named defMessgae which doesnot even exist. So when you try to access it, android will create a new preference with default value. That is why you were getting "Couldn't load data"

Comment: Actually you have ony one shared preference DefaultData = getSharedPreferences("defMobileNo",0);

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this:

```
  DefaultData = getSharedPreferences("defMobileNo",0);
  final String defNo = DefaultData.getString("defMobileNo","Couldn't load data");

  final String defMsg = DefaultData.getString("defMessgae","Couldn't load data");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how basically sharedpreference work

To Store the values

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("AUTHENTICATION_FILE_NAME", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("Name","myNameisnothing");
editor.commit();
```

To get the values

```
SharedPreferences prfs = getSharedPreferences("AUTHENTICATION_FILE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String name = prfs.getString("Name", "");
```

This way it'd return the value of the name as myNameisnothing.
PS.Correct me if im wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrongly using
`DefaultData = getSharedPreferences("defMessgae",0);` in DefSMS.java

Please remove this and it will work fine.

You were trying to get shared preference named defMessgae which doesnot even exist. So when you try to access it, android will create a new preference with default value. That is why you were getting "Couldn't load data"